# Android pass parameter to Native Activity

Tags: android, android-ndk, native-activity

My android application compirises two Activities: ".MainActivity" and "android.app.NativeActivity". The latter is implemented purely in C++. On button click in ".MainActivity" I start a native one trying to pass some parameters:

```
public void pressedButton(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, android.app.NativeActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("MY_PARAM_1", 123);
    intent.putExtra("MY_PARAM_2", 321);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

How do I get MY_PARAM_1 and MY_PARAM_2 from within android.app.NativeActivity's entry point (that is a C-function `void android_main(struct android_app* state)`)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the `android_app` structure there's a data member called `activity` of type `ANativeActivity*`. Inside the latter, there's a `JavaVM *vm` and a misleadingly called `jobject clazz`. The `clazz` is actually a JNI-compliant object instance pointer to a Java object of type `android.app.NativeActivity`, which has all `Activity` methods, including `getIntent()`.

There's a `JNIEnv` there, too, but it looks like it's not attached to the activity's main thread.

Use JNI invokations to retrieve the intent, then extras from the intent. It goes like this:

```
JNIEnv *env;
state->activity->vm->AttachCurrentThread(&env, 0);

jobject me = state->activity->clazz;

jclass acl = env->GetObjectClass(me); //class pointer of NativeActivity
jmethodID giid = env->GetMethodID(acl, "getIntent", "()Landroid/content/Intent;");
jobject intent = env->CallObjectMethod(me, giid); //Got our intent

jclass icl = env->GetObjectClass(intent); //class pointer of Intent
jmethodID gseid = env->GetMethodID(icl, "getStringExtra", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;");

jstring jsParam1 = (jstring)env->CallObjectMethod(intent, gseid, env->NewStringUTF("MY_PARAM_1"));
const char *Param1 = env->GetStringUTFChars(jsParam1, 0);
//When done with it, or when you've made a copy
env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(jsParam1, Param1);

//Same for Param2
```

Comment: Thank you. But it has raised another question unclear to me: can I use `state->activity->env` as is, or have I to acquire it using `state->activity->vm->AttachCurrentThread(&env, 0);`?

Comment: Hm... I'm looking at the thread startup code (in android_native_app_glue.c), and it looks like it's not attached to the native activity thread. So yeah, you have to attach a JVM to the thread first instead of using `env`. Edited the answer.